# ImportError: No module named _____ -- in python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble importing modules such as pandas and BS4 in python on VScode, after pip installing them through terminal.

I receive the same error message "ImportError: No module named bs4" every time.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Which command you have used to install bs4?

Comment: Could it be python vs. pip versioning? For example, are you installing with pip instead of pip3 and running python instead of python3, or vice versa?

Comment: I've used "pip install bs4" and "pip3 install bs4". I'm a newer programmer so I'm not very sure of how versioning works in python

Comment: It's possible you installed them in a `venv` and you are not using it or the opposite
, Also try relaunching vscode sometimes it helps

Comment: It is very easy to have more than one Python installation without realizing it. Do `pip --version` to find out which Python it is installing to. Then check VScode to see which Python it is  running.

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall your Python and install it again.
- Don't install packages through the VSCode terminal.
- Install them outside the VSCode and then import them into your program.
- For installing `bs4`, use the following command:

```py
pip install beautifulsoup4
```